# How to return data in JSON hierarchy?

Tags: postgresql

For the following data tables and function in **pg12**

```
create table orders
(
  orderid integer, grandtotal numeric(10, 2)
)

create table odetails
(
  orderid integer, detailid integer, description text
)

create function jorder() returns json as
begin
 return query select od.orderid, od.grandtotal, ds.detailid, ds.description
 from orders od
 join odetails ds on od.orderid = ds.orderid;
end;
```

How do I get return data in a JSON hierarchy like below?

```
[{
    "orderid": 1,
    "grandtotal": 100.00,
    "details": [{
            "detailid": 11,
            "description": "pen"
        },
        {
            "detailid": 12,
            "description": "orange"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "orderid": 2,
    "grandtotal": 200.00,
    "details": [{
            "detailid": 21,
            "description": "book"
        },
        {
            "detailid": 22,
            "description": "coffee"
        },
        {
            "detailid": 23,
            "description": "tea"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: You should fix your question: the code you provided has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) . You need `json_build_object` to form the objects and `json_agg` to aggregate them into json array:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION jorder() 
RETURNS json 
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  SELECT 
    json_agg(orders.order)
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      json_build_object(
        'orderid', od.orderid, 
        'grandtotal', od.grandtotal, 
        'details', array_agg(
          json_build_object(
            'detailid', ds.detailid,
            'description', ds.description
          )
        )
      ) as order
    FROM 
      orders od
      JOIN odetails ds on od.orderid = ds.orderid
    GROUP BY 
      od.orderid, od.grandtotal
  ) as orders 
$$;
```

Example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e92c0872ff1213ba12a827fdbf0be07b)